# Store my values as strings in the next row of the array? two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to use a 2 dimensional array as part of the assignment.

Comment: You store data in your array within the original loop but should print it outside of the main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use your two-dimensional array, then you will need nested loops to print it out.

**for**

```
for(int i=0; i < FutureValueArray.length; ++i) {
   System.out.println("whatever you print before each row);
   for(int j=0; j < utureValueArray[i]; ++j) {
      Sytem.out.print(utureValueArray[i][j] + "\t");
   }
}
```

**for each**

```
for(String[] row : FutureValueArray) {
   System.out.println("whatever you print before each row);
   for(String cell : row) {
      Sytem.out.print(cell + "\t"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: is this correct, I feel this is what is cusing the nulls. FutureValueArray[counter][0] = Double.toString(monthlyInvestment);
            FutureValueArray[counter][1] = Double.toString(interestRate);
            FutureValueArray[counter][2] = Integer.toString(years);
            FutureValueArray[counter][3] = Double.toString(futureValue);

Comment: Run your code through a debugger or put more println() calls and you will see what exactly is going on.  If you find what happens but have a problem understanding why - come back and we will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

As in your previous post you will have a problem with exceeding the bounds of your **10** x 4 array.

Consider using **ArrayList** of String Arrays instead.  ArrayList (unlike array) can grow.

See if this small (unrelated sample) gives you enough hints:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListOfStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> los = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for(int i = 0; i<=10; ++i) {
            String[] str = {Integer.toString(i), "a" +i, "b"+i, "c" + i};
            los.add(str);
        }
        for(String[] strArray : los) {
            System.out.println();
            for(String str : strArray) {
                System.out.print(str + "\t");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: true, but I just need 10X4 so I can grasp the understanding of 2 dimensional arrays this application is for my knowledge i wont exceed the bounds, I diffiently understand what you mean though

Comment: @babaysteps - your code with two-dimensional array will work as long as you do not forget to increment the `counter` variable.

Comment: it doesn't seem to print the anything?

Comment: You still need a **nested loop** to print your stuff.

Comment: i've update my code above with the nested loop, when i run it I get null, I think their somthing wrong where am seting the values as strings ex.FutureValueArray[counter][0] = Double.toString(montlyinvestment);